# Intel Rapid Storage Manager has no Accelerate tab. How can I fix it?

Tags: intel-rst

```
System Report

System Information
OS name:  Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
OS version:  6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 7601
System name:  NP530U3C
System manufacturer:  SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
System model:  530U3C/530U4C
Processor:  GenuineIntel Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9 1,701  GHz
BIOS:  Phoenix Technologies Ltd., P08AAJ

Intel® Rapid Storage Technology
Kit installed:  11.0.0.1032
User interface version:  11.0.0.1032
Language:  English (United States)
Intel AHCI controller:  Intel(R) 7 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
Number of SATA ports:  2
Driver version:  11.0.0.1032
ISDI version:  11.0.0.1032

Hardware Information
Disk on port 0
Port location:  Internal
Status:  Normal
Type:  Hard disk
Size:  466 GB
Serial number:  
Model:  Hitachi HTS545050A7E380
Firmware:  GG2OA6C0
System disk:  Yes  
Password protected:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Native command queuing:  Yes  
SATA transfer rate:  3 Gb/s
Physical sector size:  4096 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Disk on port 1
Port location:  Internal
Status:  At risk
Type:  Solid-state drive
Size:  22 GB
Serial number:
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean this button?

[image]

[Hint #1](http://communities.intel.com/message/126846#126846) I found

> Intel requires that for use of Smart Response Technology (SRT) within RST your OS must be on either a HDD or HDD RAID (via the SATA connections I believe) and a unused SSD be available (for SSD caching).  Otherwise no SRT and the Accelerate button won't appear.Don't know why Intel should care where the OS and apps are located but they've made it a requirement for use of SRT.

[Hint #2](http://communities.intel.com/message/177191#177191) I found

> You MUST be sure that your SSD is connected to the Z77 or Z68 SATA ports, or it won't be recognized and you won't get the Acceleration button/link in the RST software. [...] My SSD happened to be plugged into the extra ones, not the Z77 native ones, so I could see and access it in Windows explorer, but not in the RST software, not in the  RAID config that blips on boot up, and not in the BIOS either when I accessed SATA.

Comment: You understood correctly. I mean it this button.
 
I looked in my BIOS, it says that the connector SATA2 Not Installed. But in Intel Rapid it displays.