# Accelerate tab missing after reinstall

Tags: windows-8, ssd, cache, acceleration, intel-rst

I had SSD caching enabled and working without problems, but I had to reinstall my Windows 8 and now can't reenable it, because the tab is missing.
I have read many similar threads and tried all suggestions:
 * switched several times between AHCI and RAID from BIOS
 * reinstalled several times Intel RST tried with and without partitions on the SSD
 * enabled and disabled Link Power Managent
 * even zeroed the SSD under Linux, but still no Acceleration tab.

I am experienced user, so modifying the registry is not a rocket since for me, but i didn't find any information on how to force caching tab from registry.
Any ideas and suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally got it working.
As posted here https://superuser.com/a/691690/248151 IRST requires some free space **at the end of the drive**, so previous time when I tried that it didn't work, because I had other volumes after C: ... shrink the last volume and you'll get acceleration options in Performance tab.

It reduced my free space with 2MB and I was able to extend the last volume back after initially shrinking it with 64MB