# No Accelerate function on Intel Rapid Storage window

Tags: windows, ssd, raid, intel-rst

I also have an issue to use Intel RST, the accelaration button does not appear to use a part of a SSD as cache for another disk.

Ive got 2 disks:

SSD with Windows 10
HD with Data
Want the Data to be accelerated

Raid in Bios is enabled
hotplug is disabled for all drives
SSD has 62 GB free and not formated space on the end for planed cache
Tried with RST Software version 15 and 14.

RST detects raid, as I would be able to add raid combinations. But I dont see the acceleration button to speed up somehow my HD.

Any idea?

PS: I read those tips, none helped: [No Accelerate button/tab on Intel Rapid Storage window](https://superuser.com/questions/546601/no-accelerate-button-tab-on-intel-rapid-storage-window)

Comment: Are you in AHCI or IDE mode? Did you change (if at all) the Interface mode before or after installing Windows?

Comment: Im am in Raid mode changed from AHCI. The RST Gui also recognized it and shows me Raid options now.